# Problem with understanding the kernel of a matrix.

Tags: linear-algebra

Let's say I have a matrix A = \begin{bmatrix}1&3&4\\2&2&4\\3&1&4\end{bmatrix}

The third vector of the matrix is a linear combination of the first two vectors.

If I use gauss elimination for Ax = 0, I arrive at: \begin{bmatrix}1&0&1\\0&1&1\\0&0&0\end{bmatrix}

I see that matrix A has two pivot elements and thus rank two.

Then I get:

dim A = dim ker(A) + dim im(A)
=>
3 = 1 + 2

im(A) = span{(1, 0, 0)', (0, 1, 1)'}

ker(A) = span{(1, 1, 0)'}

Both, Wolfram Alpha and the master solution tell me that ker(A) = span{(1, 1, -1)'}

Why?

Comment: Hint:
$$\begin{pmatrix}1&3&4\\2&2&4\\3&1&4\end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix}1\\1\\0\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} 4 \\ 4 \\ 4\end{pmatrix} \neq 0 $$

Answer (score 2):

Your reduction is $\begin{bmatrix}1&0&1\\0&1&1\\0&0&0\end{bmatrix}$ is correct.

Here $x_3$ is a parameter, and you can read the first two rows as $x_1+x_3=0$ and $x_2+x_3=0$. So the solution set is
$\begin{bmatrix}x_1\\x_2\\x_3\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}-x_3\\-x_3\\x_3\end{bmatrix} = x_3\begin{bmatrix}-1\\-1\\1\end{bmatrix}$, or Span$\left\{\begin{bmatrix}-1\\-1\\1\end{bmatrix}\right\}$, which is equivalent to Span$\left\{\begin{bmatrix}1\\1\\-1\end{bmatrix}\right\}$.